# Some uploads fail in PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem with php file upload, so..when I try to uploads **some songs, they work, but some song don't work**..so the problems is that php doesn't see my upload filed, if i try:

```
if (isset($_FILES['song'])) {
//lala
}else{
 echo 'no song';
```

I receive an echo with "No song",so here you have a firebug screenshot http://screencast.com/t/prCixoAn

I have change the file size in php.ini to 30M, and i also set the max_file_size input, any solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the post_max_size option in php.ini.  That must be larger than the value of max_file_input.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are doing this already, but you also want to set set_time_limit($amountOfTime) to something so the script doesn't time out.

Answer (score 0):

These are good things to check for problems like this: [Common Pitfalls](http://us.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php) and the general [Handling File Uploads](http://us.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)